# How can I put a WiFi client and an Ethernet client to the same group?

Tags: routing, linux-networking, router, vlan, interface

I have wireless interface wl0 and ethernet interfaces eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3 all in the same bridge br0. Now I have to put one of the wifi clients and one ethernet client to the same group so that they should be able to communicate each other and other clients (both wifi and ethernet) should not be able to communicate to these clients. I am a beginner in networking. Can I use VLAN interfaces to achieve this? How can I get this working? Any help is appreciated.